# shall we copy excel on all the machines of selenium grid

Tags: selenium, testing, grid, webdriver, data-driven-tests

I am facing a problem. I am good in selenium webdriver. Now i wish to run my datadriven test cases on mac,linux and other machines. my window machine will be my hub. shall i need to copy excel files of my data driven test cases on each machine(say node).? 
As mac does not support my xls(not intalled office). Or grid will only fetch data from my machine's xls files and run test on all different mac machines.?

Answer (score 1):

Forget Selenium for a moment, because this is not a Selenium problem.

Your (test) code reads some (.xls) data file. If you move your test code to some remote machine, and it still needs to read the data file, you will probably need to move that file as well.

Regarding your issue about Mac not supporting Excel. I very much doubt that you are using MS-Excel to read the data file. Chances are very good that you are using some kind of library, like Apache-POI, to do this. That library is a Java library. As long as your target machine can run Java, you should be good to go.